# What does gdb 'x' command do?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I am reading a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441) about hacking and it has a chapter about assembly.

Following is my tiny program written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        puts("Hello World!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the following is `gdb` test:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40050f: file main.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe708) at main.c:7
7       for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400500 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400501 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000400504 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x20
   0x0000000000400508 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x000000000040050b <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
=> 0x000000000040050f <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x0000000000400516 <+22>:    jmp    0x400526 <main+38>
   0x0000000000400518 <+24>:    mov    edi,0x4005c4
   0x000000000040051d <+29>:    call   0x4003e0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400522 <+34>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x0000000000400526 <+38>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x000000000040052a <+42>:    jle    0x400518 <main+24>
   0x000000000040052c <+44>:    mov    eax,0x0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0000000000400531 <+49>:    leave  
   0x0000000000400532 <+50>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

The following part is the things that I don't understand. **Please note that $rip is the "instruction pointer" and points to** `0x000000000040050f <+15>`

```
(gdb) x/x $rip
0x40050f <main+15>: 0x00fc45c7
(gdb) x/12x $rip
0x40050f <main+15>: 0x00fc45c7  0xeb000000  0x05c4bf0e  0xbee80040
0x40051f <main+31>: 0x83fffffe  0x8301fc45  0x7e09fc7d  0x0000b8ec
0x40052f <main+47>: 0xc3c90000  0x1f0f2e66  0x00000084  0x1f0f0000
(gdb) x/8xb $rip
0x40050f <main+15>: 0xc7    0x45    0xfc    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xeb
(gdb) x/8xh $rip
0x40050f <main+15>: 0x45c7  0x00fc  0x0000  0xeb00  0xbf0e  0x05c4  0x0040  0xbee8
(gdb) x/8xw $rip
0x40050f <main+15>: 0x00fc45c7  0xeb000000  0x05c4bf0e  0xbee80040
0x40051f <main+31>: 0x83fffffe  0x8301fc45  0x7e09fc7d  0x0000b8ec
```

First command `x/x $rip` outputs `0x40050f <main+15>:   0x00fc45c7`.

Is it the instruction at 0x40050f? 
Is `0x00fc45c7` same as `mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0` (assembled instruction at 0x40050f)?

Secondly, if it is the instruction, what are those hex numbers from the output of commands `x/12x $rip`, `x/8xw $rip`, `x/8xh $rip`?

Comment: Not to be negative, but erickson does a great job going over this in great detail...also, trying ti match what he does on (apparently) a newer 64b architecture when it's already hard (to impossible) to get his examples to work under contemporary  32b ubuntu kernels is probably not the best idea. There's a reason the book comes with Ubuntu 7.04. live cd.

Comment: @gnometorule It's not about trying his examples on my machine. I would get almost same results on old x86(some different names like rip in place of eip). This is the first time I try this kind of low level stuff, so I could be confused a little. Also, I don't ask to rephrase what the author of the book wrote but to explain what those hex numbers(ouptup of 'x' command in THIS EXAMPLE) are. I think it can be explained in a sentence or two.

Comment: Fair point (see answer), but really: work through the book using as old a unbuntu distro as you can. And when something doesn't work, try googling SO or a paper called something like "smashing the stack In 2012").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As to (1), you got that correct.

As to (2), the x command has up to 3 specifiers: how many objects to print; in which format; and what object size. In all your examples you choose to print as hex (x). As to the first specifier, you ask to print 12, 8, 8 objects.

As to the last specifier in your cases:
x/12x has none, so gdb defaults to assuming you want 4-byte chunks (which GDB calls "words", x86 calls "double words").  Generally, I'd always specify what exactly you want as opposed to falling back on default settings.

x/8xw does the same, for 8 objects, as you explicitly requested dwords now.

(The `x` command defaults to the last size you used, but the initial default for that on startup is `w` words)

---

x/8xh requests half-word sized chunks of 2 bytes, so objects printed in 2 byte chunks.  (Half-word relative to GDB's standard 32-bit word size; x86 calls this a "word").

In case you wonder why the concatenation of two neighboring values does not equal what was reported when you printed in dwords, this is because the x86 is a little-endian architecture. What that means is detailed quite well in Erickson's book again - if you look a few pages ahead, he does some calculations you might find helpful. In a nutshell, if you recombine them (2,1) (4,3), ..., you'll see they match.

Comment: Not quite -- the default is "words" -- 4 byte objects -- not "double words" -- 8 byte objects.  `x/8xw` prints words (4 bytes objects) explicitly.  You need `g` on the end for 8 byte objects.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: you're right, terminology within gdb is word (hence the w). Within intel x86 (and the book op is reading) it's dword for 4 bytes.

Answer (score 14):

```
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char) and s(string),
  T(OSType), A(floating point values in hex).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.

Defaults for format and size letters are those previously used.
Default count is 1.  Default address is following last thing printed
with this command or "print".
```

Comment: Maybe my question is more assembly question than gdb (couldn't choose better title) but `help x` doesn't help me much. Please, read the last part of my question.

Comment: @khajvah "*couldn't choose better title*" Why?

Comment: @alk Maybe it's my English but I could only explain my question on example. Without involving gdb, I cannot refer to those numbers.

Comment: All of the commands are examining memory starting from 0x40050f. The modifiers after the x determine how it is shown. If you did x/i, it would show as the instruction.

Comment: Without gdb, you could do something like  printf("%x %x\n", &main, &main+15);

Comment: @PaulBeusterien ok, so x/x shows hex interpretation of the instruction, so what does the `Size letter` do? In case of `x/i`, it makes no difference but in case of hex interpretation it has change. Are `0xc7` and `0x00fc45c7` same?

Comment: The size indicates how much data starting at that address to decode. 'b' indicates one byte - the 0xc7. 'w' indicates four bytes - the 0x00fc45c7.  Since you are running on a little-endian target the 0xc7 is the only byte shown if you ask for a single byte and the low order byte when you ask for a four-byte decoding

Answer (score 1):

##### `x` Syntax

GDB command: `x`=`eXamine memory`, syntax:

- `x`
- `x [Address expression]`
- `x /[Format] [Address expression]`
- `x /[Length][Format][Unit] [Address expression]` == `x/nfu addr`

detail syntax for:

- `x /[Length][Format] [Address expression]` == `x/nfu addr`

  - Length=Size=n

    - The repeat count is a decimal integer
    - It specifies how much memory (counting by units u) to display
    - default: 1
  - Format=f

    - The display format is one of the formats used by print
    - supported formats:

      - x - hexadecimal
      - o - octal
      - d - decimal
      - u - unsigned decimal
      - t - binary
      - f - floating point
      - a - address
      - c - char
      - s - string

        - null-terminated string
      - i - instruction

        - machine instruction
      - m - displaying memory tags
    - default: x
  - Unit= Size Modifier = u

    - b - 1 byte = 8 bits
    - h - halfword = 2 bytes =16 bits
    - w - word = 4 bytes = 32 bits
    - g - giant word = 8 bytes = 64 bits
  - Address expression = starting display address

##### Example

```
(lldb) x/4xw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 0x00010007 0x7fffffff 0x00000000 0x00000000
```

`unit` change to `giant word`=`g`：

```
(lldb) x/2xg 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 0x7fffffff00010007 0x0000000000000000
```

same address, but other formats effects:

- o - octal

```
(lldb) x/4ow 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 0200007
0x116fa69bc: 017777777777
0x116fa69c0: 00
0x116fa69c4: 00
```

- d - decimal

```
(lldb) x/4dw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 65543
0x116fa69bc: 2147483647
0x116fa69c0: 0
0x116fa69c4: 0
```

- u - unsigned decimal

```
(lldb) x/4uw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 65543
0x116fa69bc: 2147483647
0x116fa69c0: 0
0x116fa69c4: 0
```

- t - binary

```
(lldb) x/4tw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 0b00000000000000010000000000000111
0x116fa69bc: 0b01111111111111111111111111111111
0x116fa69c0: 0b00000000000000000000000000000000
0x116fa69c4: 0b00000000000000000000000000000000
```

- f - floating point

```
(lldb) x/4fw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 9.18453052E-41
0x116fa69bc: NaN
0x116fa69c0: 0
0x116fa69c4: 0
* a - address
(lldb) x/4aw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: 0x00010007
0x116fa69bc: 0x7fffffff
0x116fa69c0: 0x00000000
0x116fa69c4: 0x00000000
```

- c - char

```
(lldb) x/4cw 0x116fa69b8
error: reading memory as characters of size 4 is not supported
```

- s - string

```
(lldb) x/4sw 0x116fa69b8
0x116fa69b8: "\a"
0x116fa69ba: "\x01"
0x116fa69bc: "\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\x7f"
0x116fa69c1: ""
```

- i - instruction

```
(lldb) x/4iw 0x116fa69b8
    0x116fa69b8: 0x00010007   unknown     .long  0x00010007                ; unknown opcode
    0x116fa69bc: 0x7fffffff   unknown     .long  0x7fffffff                ; unknown opcode
    0x116fa69c0: 0x00000000   unknown     udf    #0x0
    0x116fa69c4: 0x00000000   unknown     udf    #0x0
```

- m - displaying memory tags

```
(lldb) x/4mw 0x116fa69b8
error: invalid gdb format string '4mw'
```

##### Refer

- [GDB Command Reference - x command (visualgdb.com)](https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/x)
- [Debugging with GDB - Memory (gnu.org)](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_55.html)
- [Memory (Debugging with GDB) (sourceware.org)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Memory.html)