# What's the meaning of the output of x/ in gdb (Linux)?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm debugging a C program with gdb.

```
(gdb) r prog_name
(gdb) break main
(gdb) x/wx $esp
(gdb) 0xbffff3d0:     0xbffff60d
```

I know the meaning of the first 3 commands.

What I don't understand is the meaning of **last one** (the output of gdb after 3rd command).
Specifically, I don't understand: **$esp is a register**, hence I expect to find a SINGLE VALUE in the register, and as far as I know , registers **don't have an address**.
So, supposing that **0xbffff60d** is the value contained by register **esp**, what's ** **0xbffff3d0**** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `help x`?

Comment: I didn't. I did it right now. but I don't see any output explanation

Comment: Related [What does gdb 'x' command do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20570816) for more details about `eXamine`, other than the output format of "address: list of values" like a hexdump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from `gdb`:

```
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char) and s(string),
  T(OSType), A(floating point values in hex).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.
```

So in your case, `$esp` contains `0xbffff3d0`, and if you interpret that value as a pointer and dereference it, you'll get that `*(uint32_t *)0xbffff3d0` is `0xbffff60d`.

Comment: excuse. What does " and *(uint32_t *)0xbffff3d0 is 0xbffff60d. " mean?

Comment: I mean that if you interpret `0xbffff3d0` as a pointer, the value it's pointing to is `0xbffff60d`.  I was just using C syntax as shorthand.

Comment: As Carl said - the $esp holds a value 0xbffff3d0. $ESP is a stack pointer, therefore if you will examine memory x/wx *0xbffff3d0 you will be able to see to where it points.

Answer (score 1):

> $esp is a register

my understanding is:

- `esp` is a register
- `$esp` is the **stored value** for register `esp`

  - here the **stored value** is `0xbffff3d0`
- so `x/wx $esp` == `x/wx 0xbffff3d0`
- -> `x/wx 0xbffff3d0` means display memory value for address `0xbffff3d0`

  - the normal and expected result is what your see here:

```
(gdb) x/wx $esp
    0xbffff3d0:     0xbffff60d
```

- that is:

  - `0xbffff3d0` is memory address
  - `0xbffff60d` is value stored in address `0xbffff3d0`

##### Appendix

- gdb x command syntax

  - [c - What does gdb 'x' command do? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570816/what-does-gdb-x-command-do/77824105#77824105)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question about what the output format means (address in the first column, list of value(s) on the right.)  This looks like a cut-down version of the answer you posted on [What does gdb 'x' command do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77824105) with the examples removed.  Linking that answer in a comment on this question makes sense, but I don't think the questions are close enough that the same answer works for both.  (If it did, usually that means they're duplicates.  When not, versions of the same answer *tailored for each question*, usually not just cut down.)